# How to prevent UIview outside a ContainerView from resizing on segue

Tags: ios, swift

I have a root ViewController with two elements:

- An UIView that I want to stay there permanently.
- A ContainerView

The UIView is what I would call a "widget" that I want to keep throughout the app, and I resize it (by changing its frame) on ViewDidAppear of the root ViewController.

The ContainerView contains a NavigationController and the NavigationController segues to a TabBarController which segues to a whole lot of stuff.

Everything works just fine except for a small BIG problem. Whenever a Segue triggers, my "widget" UIView RESIZES to its original size... I have no idea why it's even happening! It's outside of EVERYTHING.

Comment: Try giving colors to your views to see which view actually resizes. Also use Debug View Hierarchy feature of xcode that show all view hierarchy at run time. From there you might get idea what actually happens.

Comment: @Irfan I do know which view is resizing, I said it's the widget UIView (Sibling to the container view), what I don't understand is why it's happening when a segue occurs inside his sibling view :(